# Microsoft Access 2016: Resetting Default Value of Combo Box (that uses equation) with Button?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, reset, default-value

I have the following code on the Reset button:

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls

        Select Case ctl.ControlType
            Case acComboBox
                ctl.Value = ctl.DefaultValue
        End Select
    Next
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

This is what my Default Value for the combo boxes look like:

```
=DLookUp("FieldName","TableName","strCriteria")
```

When I click the Reset button the combo box just displays the equation as a string `=DLookUp("FieldName","TableName","strCriteria")` instead of actually running the function. I tried using a different Default Value `=[cboName].[ItemData](#)` and it's the same issue. The Form works perfectly otherwise.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected, since `ctl.DefaultValue` returns the string default value property, not the actual calculated default value.

A possible approach is to use `Eval` to calculate the actual default value. Note, however, that numerous problems can arise when doing this, since the default value is not VBA, but an Access expression, so it has a different scope, and is sensitive to locale settings such as the list separator setting.

You can use the following line:

```
ctl.Value = Eval(Right(ctl.DefaultValue, Len(ctl.DefaultValue) -1))
```

Comment: Sorry never thanked you for your help. Much appreciated!